как сделать мультиязычность в next.js с учетом output: 'export'
подскажите, как сделать мультиязычность в next.js и при это учитывать, что build будут статичные файлы для заливки на хостинг.
-мой Next.config.mjs
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
    images: { unoptimized: true }
};
 
export default nextConfig;


Для App Router. Для Pages Router.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.

Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — из очереди проверок
